# Power BI is there an equivalent of SUMX Filter to do a DISTINCTCOUNT

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have created the following code in Power BI to give me LY sales figures for any selected range.

```
Total Net Sales LY = 
VAR MINSequentialDayNumber = MIN('Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber-LY])
VAR MAXSequentialDayNumber = MAX('Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber-LY])

RETURN
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        ALL(Dim_Date),
        'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]>=MINSequentialDayNumber && 'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]<=MAXSequentialDayNumber),[Total Net Sales])
```

I am trying to do the same for a Count of Distinct Location IDs but DISTINCTCOUNTX is not usable.
Is there a way to do this with DAX, otherwise I will have to create a separate table of distinct counts and feed in which is getting messy.

```
   Location Count LY = 
    VAR MINSequentialDayNumber = MIN('Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber-LY])
    VAR MAXSequentialDayNumber = MAX('Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber-LY])
    
    RETURN
    DISTINCTCOUNTX(
        FILTER(
            ALL(Dim_Date),
            'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]>=MINSequentialDayNumber && 'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]<=MAXSequentialDayNumber),[DistinctTransaction_ID])
```

Comment: I think something like this... DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact_Sales'[Location_ID]),
                                             FILTER(ALL(Dim_Date),
                           'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]>=MINSequentialDayNumber && 
                                  'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]<=MAXSequentialDayNumber

Comment: Distinct count does have some performance issues, you can use SUMX and it will be quicker over datasets. https://jlsql.blog/2018/02/06/sumx-vs-distinct-count/

Comment: Thanks Jon, just tried the SUMX(DISTINCT in link and is great!

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I have worked it out...

```
Location Count LY = 
VAR MINSequentialDayNumber = MIN('Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber-LY])
VAR MAXSequentialDayNumber = MAX('Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber-LY])

RETURN
    CALCULATE
        (DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact_Sales'[DistinctTransaction_ID]),
       FILTER(ALL(Dim_Date),
        'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]>=MINSequentialDayNumber && 'Dim_Date'[SequentialDayNumber]<=MAXSequentialDayNumber)
)
```

Comment: Yeah, It looks OK. Just not DistinctTransaction_ID, but Location_ID :) Did you test it and confirm?

Comment: :-0 thanks for spotting! was in process of testing now but really high numbers, that's why! thanks

Comment: Really High Numbers ? Then change the distinct count with SUMX, and test again. Only Change this line DISTINCTCOUNT('Fact_Sales'[Location_ID]) with SUMX(VALUES('Fact_Sales'[Location_ID),1).

Comment: Yes I had high numbers because it was counting the transactions not locations, once changed as you spotted to location_id it is OK